# H is a set of elements $a$ such that $(ax)^2 = (xa)^2$ for all $x$ in G. Prove H is a subgroup of G.

Tags: group-theory

It is given that H is the set of all elements $a$ in a group G such that

$(ax)^2 = (xa)^2$ for every $x$ in G .

Prove that H is a subgroup of G.

I came across this question while solving the book on Abstract algebra by Pinter.

My approach to this problem was :- consider two elements $p$ and $q$ in the set H.
Then $(px)^2 = (xp)^2$ for every $x$ in G . And 
$(qx)^2 = (xq)^2$ for all $x$ in G .

from this I was trying to show that

$(pqx)^2 = (xpq)^2$ for all $x$ in G . By which we can show that pq is also part of H. And thus H is closed with respect to products. (That H is closed with respect to inverses also needs to be proven but I am stuck in the first stage itself)

This approach worked in a previous problem where one had to show that center of a group is a subgroup. There the property of elements in the set C (the center) was 
$ax = xa$ for all $x$ in G . The lack of square term made it easy to prove. So I thought maybe I shouldn't use the same approach.

And hence I tried using $x^{-1}$ instead of $x$ in the equation for the element $q$  along with the equation for p. But that is also not working out.

If G was Abelian proving this would have been very easy. But it is not given so. Hence I am stuck.

Thanks.

Comment: For reference, this is exercise 5.D.4 in Pinter. I.e. chapter 5, set D, exercise 4.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since $p\in H$ and $qx\in G$, then
$$\left[p\left(qx\right)\right]^{2}=\left(qxp\right)^{2}.$$
Now, since $q\in H$ and $xp\in G$, then
$$\left(qxp\right)^{2}=\left(xpq\right)^{2},$$
which is what you wanted to prove.

Now you want to show that if $p\in H$, then $p^{-1}\in H$.
\begin{align*}
\left(xp^{-1}\right)^{2} & = \left(\left(px^{-1}\right)^{-1}\right)^{2}\\
 & = \left(\left(px^{-1}\right)^{2}\right)^{-1}\\
 & = \left(\left(x^{-1}p\right)^{2}\right)^{-1}\\
 & = \left(\left(x^{-1}p\right)^{-1}\right)^{2}\\
 & = \left(p^{-1}x\right)^{2}.
\end{align*}
This means that $p^{-1}\in H$.

Answer (score 5):

Given $p,q\in H$ we wish to show $(pqx)^{2}=(xpq)^{2}$ for all $x\in G$.

$(pqx)^{2}=(p(qx))^{2}=((qx)p)^{2}=(q(xp))^{2}=((xp)q)^{2}=(xpq)^{2}$. $x\in G$ was arbitrary.

So $pq\in H$.

Given $p\in H$ we show $p^{-1}\in H$.

$(p^{-1}x)^{2}=((x^{-1}p)^{-1})^{2}=(x^{-1}p)^{-1}(x^{-1}p)^{-1}=(x^{-1}p)^{-2}=((x^{-1}p)^{2})^{-1}=((px^{-1})^{2})^{-1}=((px^{-1})^{-1})^{2}=(xp^{-1})^{2}$.

So $p^{-1}\in H$.

Comment: -1 because you left out an essential part of the proof, showing that $H$ is closed under inverses.

Comment: Didn't notice that OP also asked for that. I shall correct that right away.

Comment: I undid my downvote because it is unclear what the actual question is anyway.

Comment: @user1 I do not think the question is unclear. While the edit now contains a proof of "stage two," I do not think an answer talking about stage one but not stage two would deserve a downvote. Answers do not need to involve complete proofs, they only need to be useful.